# Cross Promoting other apps in corona sdk?

Tags: coronasdk

Is it possible to have a cross promotion page on your app that looks like the app store using LunarAds?

Here is an image of what I am talking about:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2944741/CrossPromote.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a web view with a list of the apps. Customize the html to look like an iOS table view with a html/css framework such as [UIUIKit](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-universal/downloads/list).